# How to logout a user when a new user logs in in the same browser?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm facing this problem where I have two dashboards for two users, one is admin and the other is a merchant. The problem is when admin logs in and in the new tab a merchant logs in too. If I refresh the admin page I get a navbar that is meant for merchant and the rest of the page is of admin... I'm storing the token in localStorage.

Can anyone tell me how I can logout the previously logged in user, If a new user logs in in the on the same browser?

Comment: If two dashboards are under different domains, you can use cookies and share those cookies with different subdomains. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookies-between-subdomain-and-domain for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to log out in the other tabs it would help to pass the signal between multiple tabs you can use a local storage event.

Set a logout-event on the previous tabs

```js
localStorage.setItem('logout-event', 'logout' + Math.random());
```

Every other tab will listen it with the the code below.

```js
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event){
    if (event.key == 'logout-event') { 
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Simply put whenever a merchant logs in using a new tab follow the above procedure to logout any other user.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore IE, I prefer using Broadcast Channel API instead of localStorage event

Init your broadcast channel and listen the event

```js
const bc = new BroadcastChannel("your_channel_name")

bc.onmessage = (e) => {
  // Business logic here
  // data sent through the channel is available at e.data
}
```

When you want to trigger the event

```js
bc.postMessage("your logout message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead using localStorage, you should use sessionStorage when you want the token to be unique to each tab/session and to be deleted when tab is closed for ex

Answer (score 0):

U can use sessionStorage Instead of localStorage:
look at this:
https://hashnode.com/post/how-to-handle-multi-user-login-in-same-browser-cjbxct3yq06mk4cwty2bmpsn1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).